# Efficiently factorize a KKT system with block diagonal upper corner

Tags: linear-algebra, factorization, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-inverse, quadratic-programming

I have a system resulting from a quadratic energy minimization with linear equality constraints enforced with Lagrange multipliers which has the form:

\begin{equation}
A = 
\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
\tilde{Q}&B^T \\
\hline
B&*\\
\end{array}\right] =
\left[\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
Q & *& *& *&* \\
 *& Q &*&*&* \\
 *&*& \ddots&*&*& B^T\\
 *&*&*& Q& * \\
 *&*&*& *&Q  \\
\hline
  & &B& & &*\\
\end{array}\right] ,
\end{equation}
where $*$ means all zeros.

Let's say that $Q$ is a symmetric positive-definite $n$ by $n$ matrix and $B$ is $n*k$ by $m$ and full column rank. Both are **sparse** (small number of non-zeros per row).

I can factorize $A$ using sparse LDL decomposition but this doesn't take advantage of the repeated nature of the upper left corner.

Knowing that a factorization of $\tilde{Q}$ will just be a repeated block diagonal made up of factorizations of $Q$, 
I tried using the [Schur complement method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement), but then it seems I need to factorize $B \tilde{Q}^{-1} B^T$ which could be **dense**.

Is there a way to build a LU-style factorization for $A$ (for efficient solving) which takes advantage of both the sparsity of $Q$ and $B$ and the repeated block diagonal in $\tilde{Q}$?

Comment: I don't see why a Schur complement involves $BA^{-1}B^T$; shouldn't it be $B\tilde{Q}^{-1}B^T$, which should be computable efficiently? I assume that $m$ is small enough that you can store it densely?

Comment: You're right, that was a typo. But no, $m$ could be large perhaps even $m=n$ which for us could be >100,000. Where the number of non-zeros per row would be more like 10.

Comment: You might consider looking on this [Acta Numerica](http://mathcs.emory.edu/~benzi/Web_papers/bgl05.pdf) paper and find what suits your problem the most. If the Schur complement $B\tilde{Q}^{-1}B^T$ is well-conditioned, you can try to solve $B\tilde{Q}^{-1}B^T$ iteratively. Note that as you need to implement only the matrix-vector product for the Schur complement, you don't need to form it explicitly. Also, if $B\tilde{Q}^{-1}B^T$ is dense, then the $LDL^T$ factorisation will most likely compute dense $L$ factor too.

Comment: @PavelJiranek, the about $LDL^T$ being dense, won't the reordering (try to) mitigate this?

Comment: It's possible. There are some references, e.g., [here](http://www2.cs.cas.cz/~tuma/ps/032108.ps.gz) and [here](http://www-devel.cs.ubc.ca/~rbridson/kktdirect/kktdirect.pdf). It really depends on the application (in particular, the structure of $B$.